# Convert dictionary to new key:value pairs in a list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I´ve seen several questions in this matter, but haven´t been able to find a solutions to adapt in my case. I got a one level dictionary with several key:value pairs, in which the keys are names and the values are always numerical (float), like the following:

```py
dict = {'keyname1':0.44,'keyname2':1.23,'keyname3':0.76}
```

And I need to create a list of dicts with two key:value pairs, like:

```py
new_dict_list  = [{'name':'keyname1', 'time':0.44},{'name':'keyname2', 'time':1.23},{'name':'keyname3', 'time':0.76}]
```

Comment: Use a list comprehension, like `[{"name": key, "time": value} for key, value in dict.items()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as simple as continuously making a dictionary with those values. We can use `dict.items()` to iterate through the items (key value pair).

```py
new_dict_list = [
    {'name': name, 'time': time}
    for name, time in dict.items()
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one please.

```
new_dict_list = [{'name': k, 'time': v} for k, v in dict.items()]
```